# How to move text next to each other using css?

Tags: html, css

Just a simple css question. Trying to move the price next to the "Quick Shop" text. Basically trying to mirror this design:

[image]

```css
  .quick_shop_container{
      width:100%;
    }
    
    .quick_shop{
      background-color:white;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    
    
    .quick_shop_text{
      float:left;
    }
    .product-item-price{
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="quick_shop_container" data-price-wrapper="">
              <button class="quick_shop">
                <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop</span>
                <div data-price-wrapper="">
                  <div class="product-item-price price" data-product-price="">| £51.95</div>
                </div>
              </button> 
  </div>
```

How do I move it?

Comment: You should use flexBox.

Comment: Edited your code to a snippet. Always prefer that over normal code.

Comment: @Beller Ah got it working thanks to flex box and using justify content to move to start and end for relevant text. Thank you

Comment: If you look at my answer, you can do it a lot simpler than your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are supposed to use float, because of Browser Compatibility etc.. but if not, I guess this would be the solution.

```css
.quick_shop_container{
  width:100%;
}

.quick_shop{
  background-color:white;
  display:inline-block;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick_shop_container" data-price-wrapper="">
  <button class="quick_shop">
    <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop</span>
    <div data-price-wrapper="">
      <div class="product-item-price price" data-product-price="">| £51.95</div>
    </div>
  </button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Although flexbox is always better for 1D design. You can make your `div` inline-block so items it is inline.

Target it using `> div`, since you do not have a class. And add float : **right** to it.

```css
.quick_shop_container{
      width:40%;
    }
    
    .quick_shop{
      background-color:white;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .quick_shop > div{
    display:inline-block;
       float:right;
    }
    
    .quick_shop_text{
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="quick_shop_container" data-price-wrapper="">
              <button class="quick_shop">
                <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop</span>
                <div data-price-wrapper="">
                  <div class="product-item-price price" data-product-price="">| £51.95</div>
                </div>
              </button> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:flex` to the `.quick_shop` class
https://jsfiddle.net/k7jr4cwv/

Answer (score 0):

Until you style it differently, a `<div>` is *always* a **block-level element**.

This leads an unstyled `<div>` to occupy its own vertical space within the document flow, beneath what has gone before.

In this case, we want to *override* that standard behaviour - so we can tell the `<div>` elements to display as if they are `inline` elements:

```
div[data-price-wrapper],
div[data-product-price] {
  display: inline;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div[data-price-wrapper],
div[data-product-price] {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick_shop_container" data-price-wrapper="">
  <button class="quick_shop">
    <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop</span>
    <div data-price-wrapper="">
      <div class="product-item-price price" data-product-price="">| £51.95</div>
    </div>
  </button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using flexbox.

```css
.quick_shop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.product-item-price {
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <button class="quick_shop">
    <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop</span>
    <span class="product-item-price price">£51.95</span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will give you the same design without using the "|" character insertion.

```css
.quick_shop_container{
  width:200px; // this is container width
}

.quick_shop{
  background-color:white;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 0.15rem #ccc;
}


.quick_shop_text{
  float:left;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}

.product-item-price-wrapper {
  
}

.product-item-price {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  border-left: solid 0.15rem #ccc;
}

.product-item-price{
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick_shop_container" data-price-wrapper="">
  <button class="quick_shop">
    <span class="quick_shop_text">Quick Shop</span>
    <div data-price-wrapper="" class="product-item-price-wrapper">
      <div class="product-item-price price" data-product-price="">£51.95</div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```